# Error when creating GCP VPC with Terraform - cannot fetch token: unexpected EOF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

when I create network vpc using terraform, it showed error "oauth2: cannot fetch token: unexpected EOF" Does anybody knows what it means?

Here is my terraform code:

```
provider "google" {
  version = "3.5.0"
  credentials = file("my_service_account_key_json_file")
  project = "myproject"
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" { #line 9
  name = "terraform-network"
}

terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "my_bucket"
    prefix = "my_folder"
    credentials = "my_service_account_key_json_file"
  }
}
```

here is the error I got when runing terraform apply:

```
google_compute_network.vpc_network: Creating...

Error: Error creating Network: Post 
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<myproject>/global/networks?alt=json: oauth2: 
cannot fetch token: unexpected EOF

  on main.tf line 9, in resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network":
  9: resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
```

Comment: I was able to run this on my own account without any issues using a service account with the editor role on my GCP project. I used the same Google provider version with Terraform v0.13.5 (latest at this time)

Comment: What is the terraform version you are using, May be try by updating it, also check relevant API's are enabled

Comment: Verify your service account to have right permissions and also try to refresh or recreate your outh2 access token. I highly recommend you to read this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) regarding authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0

Comment: @Tanjin: it is Terraform v0.12.29, provider.google v3.5.0. I doubt the service account key json file has some problem. but it was created by gcp. I just click "add key" to my service account, chose json format and downloaded it. do I need to do anything else like change chmod similar to AWS key pair?

Comment: @Prany: it is Terraform v0.12.29, provider.google v3.5.0. besides, I have enabled API: cloud resource, compute engine, storage API is already enabled.

Comment: @Prany: I already enabled cloud resource managed API, Compute Engine API and storage API before I posted this article.

Comment: @user389955 did you ensure the proper permissions were granted to the service account? See this guide (step 5): https://gmusumeci.medium.com/how-to-create-a-service-account-for-terraform-in-gcp-google-cloud-platform-f75a0cf918d1
I was able to do it with only the `editor` role on the project.

Comment: @tanjin: I followed your link and it works now. the only difference is when setting permission of service account, the original tutorial I followed said I just need to select the role as Editor, while the link you provided said I need to set several admin role like storage Admin, Compute Admin, etc, I guess the role of Editor is not enough. I am new to GCP so not very clear what it means but at least I can run terraform now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tanjin: Besides, when granting user access to this SA, the original link I followed did not say I need to set service account user role,  it only told me to set service account admin role using my email. while your link told me to grant both user role and admin role, not sure it is a reason or not.

Comment: @tanjin: today when I run again using the same credential json file which works yesterday, it failed again the the same reason. not sure what happened. does it also related to the wrong formate of the file?

Comment: @tanjin: I have another service account key json file which I created few days again in default vpc and somehow it works most of time. but I found when running terraform cmd, sometimes it showed  "Error loading zone 'us-central1-c':... token: unexected EOF" sometimes it passed. is it normal? or is my internet has problem? that is so weird. when I use AWS cloud I never have such issue.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer was created to support the community partially based on the answers provided in the comments.*

A few things to validate here:

1. Verify the Authentication key json file and path.

   A correct definition of a .json authentication key file would be: `credentials = file("/home/service-account-key.json")`, where the file "service-account-key.json" is in the directory "/home/" and was obtained using the guide [Creating and managing service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys).
2. Verify the [Service Account User role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role).

   In this particular case the role should be one granted for VPC creation like the [Compute Network Admin role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.networkAdmin), and here you can find the  complete [Compute Engine IAM roles and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) reference.

Take a look at this [How to](https://gmusumeci.medium.com/how-to-create-a-service-account-for-terraform-in-gcp-google-cloud-platform-f75a0cf918d1), which describes the whole process of creating a Service Account, giving the correct permissions and using it in terraform.